# Understanding units mod $n$ are relatively prime to $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the only invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are those that are relatively prime to $n$.

The first half is straightforward. If $i$ is relatively prime to $n$, so $\gcd(i,n) = 1$, we have $\alpha i + \beta n = 1$, so $\alpha i - 1 = (-\beta)n$, so $\alpha  i \equiv 1 \text{ mod $n$}$, and $a$ is the inverse of $i$.

The second half is less straightforward. I am trying to follow some proofs of this fact that I have found, but none of them are clear about the important step. Suppose $a$ is invertible. Then there exists $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \text{ mod $n$}$. So $ab - 1 = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $ab = 1 + kn$. The claim at this point is that we can deduce immediately that $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. To show this, I believe we would need to show that $1$ divides both $a$ and $n$ (which is rather trivially true) and that if any other integer divides both $a$ and $n$, then it must divide $1$. Suppose $\gamma$ divides $a$ and $n$. That it divides $n$ implies that it implies $ab$, so it must divide $1 + kn$. It certainly divides $kn$ because it divides $n$, and it must also divide $1$, which gives the result.

How does this proof sound?

Comment: Funny.... I thought the second part was the straightforward one.  If $m$ is not relatively prime $n$ then every multiple of $m$ will be a multiple of the $\gcd(m,n)$ and so will be equive to a mulitple of $\gcd(m,n)\pmod n$ which can never be $\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Comment: Yes... you argument and proof is good but maybe can be cleaned up and presented more efficiently.

Comment: This is correct! What you were missing is that the converse of Bezout’s Identity is also true (which you proved in your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proof is good. we can tie this all together:

$m$ is invertible $\mod n$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ so that $km \equiv 1\pmod n$ (Def)

if and only if $km -1$ is divisible by $n$ (Def)

if and only if there is an integer $j$ so that $jn = km-1$ (Def)

if and only if $km +(-j)n = 1$ (Obvious algebraic maniplation).

....

So we need to prove such $k,-j$ exist iff and only if $m,n$ are relatively prime.

....

If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime the Bezout's lemma states precisely that such $k$ and $-j$ exist

And if such $k,-j$ exist then the $\gcd(m,n)$ divides the LHS so $\gcd(m,n)|1$ and so $\gcd(m,n) =1$.  So $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: One very quick question, if you don't mind.  Is it true generally that $\gcd(m,n) \geq 1$? ($-1$ divides everything also, but certainly $-1 < 1$.) Certainly $\gcd(m,n) \mid 1$ gives $\gcd(m,n) \leq 1$ so the result follows from that.